# How to push checked checkboxes values into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'd like to push checked checkboxes values into an array, but I'm having some issue because each time I try to add it into the array it stays empty, I am probably doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

http://jsfiddle.net/fx7su2rp/689/

**HTML :**

```
<input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<button id="button" type="button">button</button>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var tmp = [];

  $("input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var checked = ($(this).val());
      tmp.push(checked);
    }
  });

  $('#button').on('click', function () {
        alert(tmp);
  });

});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you deliberately not allowing values to be removed from the array, or is that your next step?

Comment: @DavidThomas If the user removes a value I'll update it onto the array when submiting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not invoking checkbox [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event. Use this:

```
$("input[name='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var checked = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    tmp.push(checked);
  } else {
    tmp.splice($.inArray(checked, tmp),1);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fx7su2rp/694/

Comment: @Lindow,  For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse. For more info. click on link which is shared.

Comment: I see, I just saw a little problem, probably because I didn't mention it but how can I update my checkboxes when the user uncheck a value ?

Answer (score 3):

You are verifying if they are checked at the beginning (when none is checked) so this is why you get that empty array.

You should be handling clicks on the `input`s in order to update the array. Check this out.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var tmp = [];

  $("input").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var checked = ($(this).val());
      tmp.push(checked);
    } else {
      tmp.splice($.inArray(checked, tmp),1);
    }
  });

  $('#button').on('click', function () {
        alert(tmp);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<button id="button" type="button">button</button>
```

Notice the `$('input').click()` there.

Comment: What if the user clicks a checkbox 2 or more times?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle checked event of each checkbox.

So that you can push it into array 
For more detail, you can see [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var tmp = [];
  
  $("input").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      tmp.push(this.checked);
    }
});})
 
  $('#button').on('click', function () {
  alert(tmp);
    console.log(tmp);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<button id="button" type="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a click function on your checkbox and each click, if checked, then push the value in `tmp` variable.

```js
  $('#button').on('click', function () {
  var tmp = [];
      $("input").each(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var checked = ($(this).val());
          tmp.push(checked);
        }
      });
  alert(tmp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<button id="button" type="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can do on change as the other sais, but it's more effective to only run the code when the user presses the button, so make a function and call that function when the user presses the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/fx7su2rp/693/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  $('#button').on('click', function () {
        alert(check_boxes());
  });

});

function check_boxes() {
var tmp = [];
  $("input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var checked = ($(this).val());
      tmp.push(checked);
    }
  });
  return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already suggested, you have to update your values array anytime a `change` event occurs on any checkbox you wish to monitor.

Other answers work just fine, but I thought I'd post a more plain javascript answer. I think this is a bit cleaner and more expressive than a jQuery `.each()` loop, and saves us from querying values in, pushing into, and splicing from an intermediate array manually.

Let's create a regular array containing your checkboxes called `checkboxesArray` in addition to the jQuery collection, and `filter` then `map` that array in our change handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  let $checkboxes = $('[name="checkbox"]');
  let checkboxesArray = [].slice.call($checkboxes);
  let $output = $('#output');
  let values = [];
  
  $checkboxes.on('change', () => {
    values = checkboxesArray
      .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
      .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
      
    // Preview:
    $output.append('<div>' + values.join(', ') + '</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<button id="button" type="button">button</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

```
$("#button").click(function (e) { 
     var tmp = [];              
     $('.tmp').each(function(){
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     var checked = ($(this).val());
     tmp.push(checked);
   }
 });
 console.log(tmp);
}
```